# How to scrape a number from a `<span>` without an ID or class?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

My aim is to scrape from a website. I am using Cheerio and Node.js.

This is my code:

`Main.js`:

```js
const request = require('request')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const jsonFile = require('jsonfile')
request("https://nrldc.in", function(error, response, html){
  //console.log(response)

  if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
  }

  let h1 = $('div.textwidget:nth-child(1)> p:nth-child(2) > strong:nth-child(1)> span:nth-child(1)').text()

  console.log(h1)
```

This is the part of my HTML file:

```html
<div class="textwidget">
  <p></p>
  <p style="text-align: left; font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;">NR Grid Frequency: 
    <strong><span style="font-size: 23px;color:red;">49.82</span></strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to fetch the data `49.82` in the `<span>` tag. But there is no class name or id. How can I do it?

Comment: Does your current JS code not work? Are there any errors thrown? Have you tried different selectors?

Comment: No error and nothing is being retrieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('p:contains("NR Grid Frequency") span').text()
```